# Codename One add icon to title

Tags: icons, codenameone, title

I am trying to add an icon to the title/ title bar.

Changing the title itself with code works fine : 
        setTitle("Testing");

Yet I can't figure out a way to add an icon to it. Here is what I have tried, with no avail:

```
    Image img = Image.createImage("/kalender.png");
    getTitleComponent().setIcon(img);

    FontImage icon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_SEARCH, "TitleCommand", 3);
    getTitleComponent().setIcon(icon);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setTitleComponent will solve it as soon in below

```
FontImage icon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_SEARCH, "TitleCommand", 3);
   Label title = new Label(icon);
 **setTitleComponent(title);**
```

[EDIT]

```
 **getToolbar().setTitleComponent(titles);**
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately, I still don't have an icon in the title bar ...

Comment: the label display the image only if not used in the title

Comment: pls 
try this one 
   getToolbar().setTitleComponent(titles);
I have editted above also

Comment: Yes, the `getToolbar()` approach is the right one. We superseded the old API's with the `Toolbar` API's.

Comment: Many thanks to everybody for taking the time to look into this. Working perfectly now ..

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
    Form form = new Form(BoxLayout.y());
    Image icon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_CAKE, "TitleCommand", 5).toImage();
    Label tittleButton = new Label("Tittle", icon, "Label");
    form.getToolbar().setTitleComponent(tittleButton);
    form.getToolbar().setTitleCentered(true);
    form.show();
```